$\int_C \frac{\sinh(x)dy-\sin(y)dx}{\cosh(x)-\cos(y)} = \int_C \frac{-\sin(y)}{\cosh(x)-\cos(y)}dx+\frac{\sinh(x)}{\cosh(x)-\cos(y)}dy$
Calculate
$$\int_C \frac{\sinh(x) dy - \sin(y) dx}{\cosh(x) - \cos(y)} = \int_C \frac{-\sin(y)}{\cosh(x) - \cos(y)} dx + \frac{\sinh(x)}{\cosh(x) - \cos(y)} dy,$$
where $C = \{ (x,y): \ x^2 + y^2 = 1 \}$ is oriented positively.
I would like to use Green's theorem over the set $D = \{ (x,y): \ x^2 + y^2 \leq 1 \}$.
I get that
\begin{align}
&\int_D \left( \frac{\sinh(x)}{\cosh(x) - \cos(y)} \right)'_x - \left( \frac{-\sin(y)}{\cosh(x) - \cos(y)} \right)'_y \\
&= \int_D \left( \frac{\sinh(x)}{\cosh(x) - \cos(y)} \right)'_x + \left( \frac{\sin(y)}{\cosh(x) - \cos(y)} \right)'_y \\
&= \int_D \frac{[\sinh(x)]'_x(\cosh(x) - \cos(y)) - [\cosh(x) - \cos(y)]'_x \sinh(x)}{(\cosh(x) - \cos(y))^2} \\&+ \frac{[\sin(y)]'_y(\cosh(x) - \cos(y)) - [\cosh(x) - \cos(y)]'_y\sin(y)}{(\cosh(x) - \cos(y))^2} \\
&= \int_D \frac{\cosh^2(x) - \cosh(x)\cos(y) -  \sinh^2(x)}{(\cosh(x) - \cos(y))^2} + \frac{-\sin^2(y) + \cosh(x)\cos(y) - \cos^2(y)}{(\cosh(x) - \cos(y))^2} \\
&= \int_D \frac{\cosh^2(x) - \sinh^2(x) - \sin^2(y) - \cos^2(y)}{(\cosh(x) - \cos(y))^2}
\end{align}
...and I don't know what to do next. I would like to simplify that integral and use polar coordinates to evaluate it, but right now I'm not sure if that's the correct idea.

Your calculations are correct in all your steps (do not forget to add the area differential).
In your last step, using trigonometric identities, notice that
$$\cosh^2(x) - \sinh^2(x) - \sin^2(y) - \cos^2(y) =$$
$$= \left[\cosh^2(x) - \sinh^2(x)\right] - \left[\sin^2(y) + \cos^2(y)\right]$$
$$= 1-1$$
$$= 0$$
So your integral is actually $0$.
